# How to restart KEDA

Tags: keda, keda-scaledjob

After I edited a scaledjob, how to restart KEDA with the new config?

I've tried to scale it down and up, but seems it doesn't impact the settings:

```
kubectl scale deploy -n keda keda-operator --replicas=0
kubectl scale deploy -n keda keda-operator --replicas=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is no need to restart since KEDA applies config changes right after you've changed a scaledjob. Just have a good test to confirm new changes have been applied.

Comment: You should avoid changing config directly. Create/update the yaml file and then apply it